# mongoose best practices for objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a *user.js* file that contains all my mongoose schema and methods, roughly like this:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  surname: { type: String, required: true },
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Now, Is it best to expose functions that model the data? like this:

```
exports.addUser = function(data, next){
  user = new User(data);
  user.save(next);
};

exports.getAll = function(next){
  var query = User.find();
  query.exec(next);
};
```

or to expose just the `User` object to be used elsewhere like this?

```
module.exports = User; //or
exports.User = User;
```

I am also facing a problem derived from the second solution, suppose I want to add a list of cars to my `userSchema`, and the car schema is defined in another file *car.js*, then it means that I will have to expose the `carSchema` for my *user.js* file, right? This means I am actually nullifying the second solution I provided above, then, what is the right way of doing this sort of things?

Comment: I'd not spread a schema definition across multiple files for a single class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question.

This is probably just a "syntactic sugar" thing but I am sticking with the second variant because there is IMHO no need to capsule the generation etc. mongoose is the wrapper around such stuff and one can then use the pure mongoose Models and Schemas. Does this sounds reasonable for you?

```
exports.User = User;
```

Comment: Totally agree. If the need arises to implement custom functions related to a model, Mongoose has interfaces to implement [static](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) and [instance](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) methods, too.

Comment: It does make sense but what if, as stated in the question, User also contains another schema? Imagine a userSchema that also has cars like that: `cars: [carSchema]`. then do I also need to have in car.js something like `exports.carSchema = mongoose.Schema({whatever})`?

Comment: I hope I got you right. Please have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/johannesboyne/8347861 as you see I used this mongoose method `orgas: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Organization'}] ` to link them but of cause had to export both schemas. It feels right because for each schema a new Document-Collection is created in our MongoDB, isn't it?

Comment: have a look at this question, I explained it in more detail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023089/mongoose-possible-circular-dependency