# nodejs mongoose : cyclic dependency detected

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm getting a cyclic dependency exception whereas I don't find any cyclic possibility in the very simple code at this point. I'm expecting it is happening due to population between two mongoose models but as said here : [mongoose - possible circular dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023089/) this shouldn't produce this kind of error so I don't understand.

model\customer.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var customerSchema = new Schema({
  _siretCustomer:
    { type: String, required: true, minlength: 15, maxlength: 15, index: {unique: true} },
  fileNumberCustomer:
    { type: String, required: true, minlength: 6, maxlength: 6 },
  companyTypeCustomer:
    { type: String, required: true },
  companyNameCustomer:
    { type: String, required: true },
  contactName1Customer:
    { type: String, required: false, default: null },
  contactName2Customer:
    { type: String, required: false, default: null },
  landlineContact1Customer:
    { type: String, required: false, default: null },
  landlineContact2Customer:
    { type: String, required: false, default: null },
  emailContactCustomer:
    { type: String, required: false, default: null },
  obligationCommentCustomer:
    { type: String, required: false, default: null },
  taskCommentCustomer:
    { type: String, required: false, default: null },
  creationDateCustomer:
    { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  userCustomer:
   [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true }]
}, { collection: 'customer' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', customerSchema, 'customer');`
```

model\user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    _trigramUser:
        { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    lastnameUser:
        { type: String, required: true },
    firstnameUser:
        { type: String, required: true },
    privilegeUser:
        { type: String, required: true, enum: ['Accountant', 'Social operator'] },
    dateCreationUser:
        { type: Date, default: Date.now  },
    passwordUser:
        { type: String, required: true },
    customersUser:
        [{ type: String, ref: 'Customer'}]
}, { collection: 'user'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'user');
```

controller\session\customerController.js

```
exports.readCustomer = (req, res) => {
    database.getConnection();
    customer.find(req).populate('userCustomer').exec((err, customer) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err.stack);
    res.status(200).json(customer);
  });
};
```

Comment: The cause is maybe req object. I recommend you to use only req.param or req.query depending on which type of request you make

Comment: Yes this was the problem, thank you a lot for your help!
Using 'req.body', 'req.params' or 'req.query' works fine.